ConnectivityChanged Handler is not triggering on connection change in .NET MAUI
This is my View Model Implementation in which I am handling the Connection Changed Event in Constructor.
But why the handler is not triggering when I am trying to turn on/off the connection?
I am using the Android 14.0 - API 34

        [ObservableProperty]
        private UserModel _userModel = new();

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _isRefreshing;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _internetConnected;
        public UserViewModel(IUserService userService,IDialogService dialogService,IToastService toastService,INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;
            _toastService = toastService;
            _dialogService = dialogService;
            _userService = userService;
            userList = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();
            InternetConnected = true;
            if(Connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                InternetConnected = false;
            }
            Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += ConnectivityHandler;
        }

        private async void ConnectivityHandler(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                InternetConnected = true;
                await _toastService.ShowToast("Back Online", ToastDuration.Short, 20);
                await GetAllUsers();
                IsRefreshing = false;
                return;
            }
            InternetConnected = false;
        }

My Handler should be trigger and I should be able to debug my code.

You can refer to this issue: Fix connectivity broadcast receiver never triggered on android 14.0/34+ #19968. In addition, try to add a breakpoint to debug? also can see official code sample.

Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue on 14
